# How to loop on each worksheet in the workbook to do calculation?

Tags: vba, excel

i am having problem with the task i am doing right now. Supposedly,i have a for loop to calculate the *MIN* and *SUM* of the used range (tables). Since i have 10 worksheet in the workbook, i added another for loop to loop on each worksheet in the workbook. However, the codes run without error but the output is not as expected. It will calculate even at the  unused range. Is there any error on my code?

```
Sub calc()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim y As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer, r As Long, j As Long

Set y = ThisWorkbook

For Each ws In y.Worksheets
For Each rng In ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3).Areas
    If rng.Rows.Count > 1 And rng.Columns.Count = 14 Then
        j = 2
        r = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, 1).Row + 1
        Cells(r, rng.Columns(1).Column).Value = "SUMMARY"
        For i = rng.Columns(2).Column To rng.Columns(2).Column + 12
            If i = rng.Columns(12).Column Then
                Cells(r, i).Formula = "=MIN(" & rng.Columns(j).Address & ")"
                j = j + 1
                Else
                Cells(r, i).Formula = "=SUM(" & rng.Columns(j).Address & ")"
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next rng
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always qualify which sheet you are referring to when you use `Cells`, `Range`, etc.

For instance, the line

```
Cells(r, rng.Columns(1).Column).Value = "SUMMARY"
```

is referring to the **active** sheet, but you probably want to refer to the sheet that `ws` is referring to, i.e.

```
ws.Cells(r, rng.Columns(1).Column).Value = "SUMMARY"
```

Your code should probably look like:

```
Sub calc()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim y As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer, r As Long, j As Long

Set y = ThisWorkbook

For Each ws In y.Worksheets
For Each rng In ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3).Areas
    If rng.Rows.Count > 1 And rng.Columns.Count = 14 Then
        j = 2
        r = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, 1).Row + 1
        ws.Cells(r, rng.Columns(1).Column).Value = "SUMMARY"
        For i = rng.Columns(2).Column To rng.Columns(2).Column + 12
            If i = rng.Columns(12).Column Then
                ws.Cells(r, i).Formula = "=MIN(" & rng.Columns(j).Address & ")"
                j = j + 1
            Else
                ws.Cells(r, i).Formula = "=SUM(" & rng.Columns(j).Address & ")"
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next rng
Next

End Sub
```